# Reverse Accordion Direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation, accordion

Here is the [Zurb Accordion Foundation Documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html)

How do I reverse the direction my Zurb Accordion opens?

[Here is the demo link](http://beekman.qsandbox.com/) - and access code is **000**

I wish for the accordion to slideup / vertically up / upwards - not down.
Pure CSS would be wicked, but if J$ works, that's great too!

:)

Thanks for your attention

Comment: try .slideToggle(), .slideUp()

Comment: When I wrapped this code --> http://jsfiddle.net/7xnep/ into <script> tag I had no luck

Comment: you didnt include the ZURB library in the fiddle

Comment: can you create a fiddle, you can use use any of the 2 functions mentioned

Comment: Check out this instead of the above fiddle --> http://codepen.io/Maggew/pen/dErxv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Try using this**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rycFJ)

I ve customised according to it. So that it comes upwards... i think it ll help you

```
.accordion .accordion-navigation.active > a, .accordion dd.active > a {
      background: #e8e8e8;
       position:relative;
        top:85px; // Change this
      }
    .accordion .accordion-navigation > a, .accordion dd > a {
      background: #efefef;
      color: #222222;
      padding: 1rem;
      display: block;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1rem; }
      .accordion .accordion-navigation > a:hover, .accordion dd > a:hover {
        background: #e3e3e3; }
    .accordion .accordion-navigation > .content, .accordion dd > .content {
      display: none;
      padding: 0.9375rem; }
      .accordion .accordion-navigation > .content.active, .accordion dd > .content.active {
        display: block;     
        background: white; 
        position:relative;
        top:-55px; // Change this too
        }
```

The only thing u have do is... u got to position the child div...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**JS:**

```
$(".accordion").on("click", "dd:not(.active)", function (event) {
  $("dd.active").removeClass('active').find(".content").slideUp("slow");
  $(this).addClass('active').find(".content").slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

Comment: When I copy pasted your chunk of code into the CodePen @ http://codepen.io/Maggew/pen/dErxv it didn't solve problem. The animation was enhanced with a slow effect though!